# Logging Errors and Timeouts in Warp

Tags: haskell, servant, haskell-warp

Some context: My Servant handler is executing a long-running computation. Due to me using a plain `return` statement in the handler, it returns immediately and the actual computation takes place lazily when Warp tries to send the response to the client. This causes Warp to trigger slowloris timeouts because there is no network progress for a long time.

I fixed it by forcing the result inside the service handler. However, this issue was difficult to diagnose with no indication as to what is happening at either compile time or runtime, so I would like to avoid that in the future.

I do not know if there is a way to catch this mistake at compile time, but I would like to at least trace it at runtime:

1. All requests and responses should be logged
2. Errors and timeouts should be indicated as such in the log
3. Ideally, both the start and the completion of a request should be indicated in the log

I have looked at the `wai-logger` package, which I can use with Warp's own `setLogger` setting to install a logger. It seems like this only logs when a request is completed. In particular, there is no log entry at all if a request runs into an error or a timeout.

I have also looked at the `RequestLogger` module from `wai-extra`, which uses a middleware to do the logging. In the situation I described above, this results in an immediate log entry indicating success, even if the response has not been sent yet (because the response body is computed lazily). Again, there is no indication of an error or a timeout.

What is the best way to log all requests and responses, including errors and timeouts, in a Warp application?

#### Update #1

Since an example was requested:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp
import Servant

type Service = Get '[JSON] Int

service :: Server Service
service = return $ sum [0..100000000000]

main :: IO ()
main = run 3000 $ serve @Service Proxy service
```

When using `curl http://localhost:3000`, I get `curl: (52) Empty reply from server` after exactly one minute (2x 30s default timeout).

Curiously, running `curl http://localhost:3000` repeatedly eventually completes the request successfully. Maybe the `sum [0..100000000000]` results in a partially evaluated thunk whose evaluation can be resumed in subsequent requests? I am really not sure though.

The issue is fixed by using `return $! sum [0..100000000000]` instead.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example?

Comment: @leftaroundabout I added an example of the original issue, I hope this is what you meant.

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately I don't have an answer though.

Comment: This is not really a solution, but the closest thing I have found so far is using `Network.Wai.Handler.Warp.setOnException` to install a custom exception logging function. This at least enables me to log something like "SomeAsyncException: Thread killed by timeout manager" in the case discussed above. It is not great and there seems to be no way to associate the exception to a particular request, but it is better than nothing.